Add Row Pointer Hand Cursor Adding Unintended Rows When Hovering Between Two Rows - Online Excel
Users are reporting that their cursor changes to a pointer hand when hovering between two rows on the row numbers. What is this new feature and how do I turn it off? It is causing unintended rows to be added to a spreadsheet that shouldn't be modified.


If they hover between a row/column while the cursor is a hand, they can insert a new row/column by clicking. If they shouldn't be modifying a spreadsheet then you could make it read only. If users make mistakes in their spreadsheets they can click Undo.

Thanks Blindspots. I understand the problem. Is there a way to turn it off?

Yes, disable their ability to insert rows.
